# How can I prefill a text area with a long blob in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text, blob, erb

In one of my views I have this code:

```
<%= f.label :default_theme %>
<%= f.text_area(:default_theme, :value => "How do we fill this with a long blob?") %>
```

I want to pre populate the text area, but with a very long blob of over 160 lines of xml. What is the best way to do this? I understand I could just fill it in as a value, but that seems to be a really horrible way of doing it.

Comment: in your controller, use a XML-reader that will load the "long-message", put it into a shared variable `@default_theme_content` for example, and then call it for your text_area: `f.text_area(:default_theme, :value => @default_theme_content)`

Comment: Ah I see. Would if be preferred to do this in the model rather than controller?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a XML-reader library to load the long message into a shared variable `@default_theme_content` for example:

```
def index
  @default_theme_content = MyXMLReader.read('path/to/xml/file.xml')
  # etc.
```

And then use it in your view:

```
f.text_area(:default_theme, :value => @default_theme_content)
```

---

You also asked if this should be in the model rather than Controller. It depends:

**1):** If your file is related to a Model, like a Theme model, and should be loaded as the default Theme for a User, then yeah you could have a method in your model to return this file:

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  # etc.

  def self.default_theme_content
    MyXMLReader.read('path/to/xml/file.xml')
  end
```

And use it like this in the controller:

```
def index
  @default_theme_content = Theme.default_theme_content
  # etc.
```

**2):** If this file is not related to any model, you can delegate this to the controller.